# Node http-server not working on Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just tried to install NodeJS `http-server` on Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash, installation worked fine but running it to serve a static site `$http-server src` throws this error:

```
$ http-server src

/usr/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server:14
var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
                ^
Error: EINVAL, invalid argument
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server:14:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

What can be missing here? Not supported yet with Ubuntu bash on Windows 10?

Comment: Likely not supported yet, `EINVAL` is a linux system error and MS are emulating or mapping system calls to windows. Last time I heard the devs talk they weren't too sure about anything servery working to well

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** This issue has been fixed since the Windows 10 Creators Update (April 2017).

This is currently a known issue[[1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/118)][[2](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/744)][[3](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/468)][[4](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/69)] with regards to some low-level networking code that has not yet been implemented for Bash on Windows or the Windows-Linux Subsystem (WSL).

Until it is fixed, you can try using `live-server`:

```
sudo npm install live-server -g
live-server src
```

or possibly Python's SimpleHTTPServer:

```
cd src
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

To help fix it sooner, it is suggested that you vote for the issue on the [Bash on Windows Uservoice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13383789-enable-network-interface-enumeraration) as Microsoft will be using those votes to determine which issues to prioritize for fixing in any upcoming updates.